# Installing Visual Studio 2017 RC breaks dotnet core 1.0.1?

Tags: c#, .net-core, visual-studio-2017

I can no longer build projects that are using .net core 1.0.1, once I install Visual Studio 2017 RC, so it's not as "side by side" as we might have hoped.

When I build I get this error:

```
D:\dev\app >dotnet build
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 15.1.0.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Build started 11/28/2016 10:35:13 AM.
     1>Project "D:\dev\...\app.xproj" on node 1 (Build target(s)).
     1>D:\dev\..\app.xproj(7,3): error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\1.0.0-preview3-004056\Extensions\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\DotNet\Microsoft.DotNet.Props" was 
not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and 
that the file exists on disk.
     1>Done Building Project "D:\dev\...\app.xproj" (Build target(s)) -- FAILED.

Build FAILED.
```

Update: I have documented a workaround in the comments, but if there's a way to get both preview3 and preview2 tooling to work "side by side" that's what this question is asking.

Comment: workaround: Rename folder C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\1.0.0-preview-3 by putting a tilde or dollar sign in front of it, leaving only the preview2 tooling folder.  Intention of workaround is to let preview2 tooling function fine even though the 2017RC shipped a broken set of tools.

Comment: alternative workaround might be to go to add-remove-programs and find the dotnet preview3 tooling item and remove it, which would probably have approximately the same effect.

Comment: As the final result would be an SDK out of preview, I think it would be a temporary "known issue" with no fix. Another workaround is to run `dotnet migrate` to fully switch to preview 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proper way to make sure the right .net core tools gets used is a file called `global.json` in your solution dir that should reference your desired tools:

```
{
  "projects": [ "src", "test" ],
  "sdk": {
    "version": "1.0.0-preview2-003121"
  }
}
```

Comment: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/PublishingASPNETCore11ApplicationsToAzureUsingGitDeploy.aspx

Comment: Where does the global.json live?

Comment: Solution directory is where